# MySQL search algorithm for best match

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

i have a problem . I am creating a product suggestions functionality based on the subcategories of products. Suppose i have subcategories like

**Case 1 (if i have 2 words)**

1. TV has 1 products
2. Samsung TV has 1 products
3. Samsung refrigerator has 1 product
4. Samsung fridge  has 1 product

What i want is if i enter **Samsung TV** then i want products from `TV` or `Samsung TV` but not from `Samsung refrigerator` or `Samsung fridge` . what i have tried is

```
select * from tabel name where title like "%Samsung TV%" or title like "%Samsung" or title like "%TV"
```

**case 1 PROBLEM**

it also select the products from **Samsung refrigerator** and **Samsung fridge**

**Case 2(when words are more than 2)**

1. Samsung washing machine has 1 products
2. Tata washing machine has 1 products
3. Samsung washing device has 1 product
4. washing machine  has 1 product

What i want is if i enter **Samsung washing machine**. the query i wrote is

```
select * from tabel name where title like "%Samsung washing machine%" or title like "%Samsung washing%" or title like "%washing machine%"
```

**case 2 PROBLEM**

Till now no problem but better solution will be appreciated . 
[image]
huge Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the fascinating world of regular expressions

Comment: Take a look at full-text indexes

Comment: full text index will select all matching items . what do you think @Yann39

Comment: @Strawberry can you please explain or a link ?

Comment: @ShowStopper There are a few options you can use in full text search queries, for example `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(title)
AGAINST('+samsung -TV' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` will return rows containing _samsung_ but not _TV_. There are a lot of other operators like `+` or `-`. You can also filter by score, etc. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) ;)

Comment: Add parent categories to the query. Tvs, regardless of brand, will only be in the TV category so that will stop any fridges etc coming through. Proper database management will make this a lot easier

Comment: @Matt i have category in the db but how can i get results from the same category ?

Comment: have a look here http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1316929/83c34038dabb9448d9c4a4059bdf4a14

Comment: Store some preg matches, if tv is in the string then choose only records for cat_id = tv. Do this for all cat ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:-

```
select *  from department  where Name like "%Samsung" or (Name like "%Tv%" and Name like "%Samsung%") UNION select  from department  where Name like "%tv" or (Name like "%Samsung%" and Name like "%TV%")
```

Hope this will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

better you use just and

```
select * from tabel name where title like "%TV" or (title like "%Samsung%" and title like "%TV%")
```

Comment: but if i add `bikes sports` then according to this query it'll select all sports item from `shoes sports` or `items sports` etc

Comment: if the query is select * from tabel name where (title like "%bikes%" and title like "%sports%"), then no

Comment: then this query will not select products from `bikes` subcategory

Comment: ah, you mean that. then this: select * from tabel name where title like 'bikes%' or (title like "%bikes%" and title like "%sports%")

Comment: haha. . but i how can i switch to fist and second words programmatically ?

Comment: you parse inputs, get the $first and $second word. concat with string "title like '$first%'", and concat again with second filter, "(title like '%$first%' and title like '%$second%')"

Comment: i know that how to get first and second words . according to your query how would i know `'$first%'"` or  `'$second%'"` ??

Comment: wuow we've been warned of extended comments. lastly, it's up to your logic whether to the first is a subcategory, or second is a containing searched word. i'm just trying to help :)